# Сохранить setAttribute из localStorage при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Добавить/удалить `setAttribute` получилось. Но как сохранить атрибут у `body` при перезагрузке страницы?

Вот мой код:

```
document.getElementById('switch').onclick = function () {
if(document.body.hasAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')){
    document.body.removeAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    localStorage.removeItem('data-theme');
} else {
    document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    localStorage.setItem('data-theme', 'dark');


    let darkmode = localStorage.getItem('data-theme');
    darkmode = darkmode ? JSON.parse(darkmode) : {};
    darkmode['data-theme'] = 'dark';

    localStorage.setItem('data-theme', JSON.stringify(darkmode));
}
};
```

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы при рендере станицы, происходила проверка localStorage пользователя на наличие там `data-theme`, и если значение есть, то в `body` передавалось это значение, а если нет, то выставлялось по умолчанию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
let key = 'data-theme';
let value = 'dark';
let theme = localStorage.getItem(key);

if (theme) {
 document.body.setAttribute(key, theme);
}

document.getElementById('switch').onclick = function () {
if(document.body.hasAttribute(key, value)){
    document.body.removeAttribute(key, value);
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
} else {
    document.body.setAttribute(key, value);
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}
};
```